# How to copy several files to various folders based on a source and destination list in eXcel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, shell, vba, copy

How to  copy several files from a single folder to different folders in windows having a source and destination list in eXcel?

I have a folder with few PDF files.
I want to move each PDF file to its specific destination folder.
I have the list of destination folders (Full Path) in eXcel
and also the list of the PDF file names in eXcel..

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I don't know how to do. Any way to do without manual doing?

Comment: If you are going to do this a lot then google "how to copy files using VBA in Excel" (basic coding skills required). If you only want to do this once or twice, structure your data like this in a row "copy", "file1.pdf", "c:\pdfs\books" (without commas or quotes). Now select all and copy. Open notepad and paste. Create an extra line below and type "pause". Save file as excelcopy.bat in the source pdf folder. Now run that batch script by double clicking in windows explorer. If it doesn't work the file was saved excelcopy.bat.txt (rename in command prompt). Can also use "move" instead of "copy".

Comment: Since in Windows path and filenames, you may have space as valid character, I suggest you use Mobus trick by adding two columns (actually 4) with `" `before and after the filename and path name. Copy the text to the batch file and run it in a shell (in principle you can also paste everything directly into the shell). Note that you can use `cmd.exe`, powershell, the Linux shell and for each of them you should use the appropriate syntax. PS> Welcome on SuperUser.